# Valid SQL query fails in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So. I'm working on a simple system. I have the following code:

```
$sql = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$aaa="SELECT UserName,activeuntil from sessions WHERE `sessionid`='$b' AND `sessiontype`=$a";
$sqc=mysqli_prepare($sql,$aaa);
mysqli_execute($sqc);
mysqli_bind_result($sqc,$un,$til);
while(mysqli_fetch($sqc)){echo $un;if(strtotime($til)>time())$user=$un;}
echo "Hi, $user";
```

which $aaa produces in my case:

```
SELECT UserName,activeuntil from sessions WHERE `sessionid`='rc1xamoblbqxul78czfsvub62fudzc' AND `sessiontype`=0
```

which is a perfectly running query in PhpMyAdmin. However, the code overall does not produce a result (should have 1 line). Why? I guess I'm missing something very easy, but what?

P.S.: if you can only say "please sanitize your inputs", "this coding style is horrible", don't answer this as these will be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Fix the things you know to be wrong before trying to figure out what else might not be right.

Comment: This is more important as sanitizing would be needed WAY later (currently won't be public).

Comment: I don't see `$a` or `$b` defined in your code.

Comment: They are defined before. ($a is 0 and $b is rc1xamoblbqxul78czfsvub62fudzc in the case).

Comment: But your embedding of variables into your SQL (of a prepared statement, no less!) might well be causing your problem here.  So, given you know that to be wrong and that it'd take a second to fix, why not do that first?

Comment: Nice variable naming...very meaningful and easy to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot a trivial, non-SQL related thing (an include statement...). Thanks for all the answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$query ="SELECT UserName,activeuntil from sessions WHERE 'sessionid'='$b' AND 'sessiontype'=$a";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
{
echo "Hi ".$row->UserName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have a query issue in php I echo my SQL string and run it in PHPmyAdmin. If it executes fine then your connection has an error. Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in a question, it executed fine. However, mysqli_error gives blank result, theefore no error in the connection.